# Is there a way to transfer table data from Access to Quickbooks with new ID?

Tags: ms-access, quickbooks

I am currently testing QODBC and OpenSync to find a way to let me enter information through Access and have it sync and show up in QuickBooks.

QuickBooks auto generates keys for each entry, but when entering new data the user is left to enter all of the fields themselves including the ID field. Is there a way to make Access generate QuickBooks ID's?

By ID I mean the primary ID field in each table is empty and is filled with Quickbook keys.

Answer (score 0):

Are you letting the users type directly into the tables?

In every QODBC application I have written, Access uses a front end to gather the data and then create the new record using VBA. When Access generates a new record that is QODBC linked, QuickBooks automatically assigns a new primary key ID to it.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how your application is making QODBC makes QuickBooks generate a new Primary ID?

Comment: Standard SQL `INSERT` statements is one way: `DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [QODBC linked table] ([FieldNames]) VALUES ([Values to be Inserted])"`. No primary key needed, it is auto-generated.